# Java, Compare Small 2D Array to Each Possible Iteration within a larger 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Okay so I need to be able to search through a large array (say 15x20, or 20x17) of what is a field of nothing but ones and zeroes to find which 13x13 number template their layout most accurately reflects, in a kind of primitive OCR. My problem is that I need to move a 13x13 array through each possible iteration of the larger array to see where it most closely matches the digit array. This is what I've tried:

```
  public double compareMatrices(int[][] num,int[][] mat){
    double score=0;
    double highest=0;
    int n=0;
    for(;n+num.length<mat.length;n++){
        int[][] rows=new int[num.length][];
        int m=0;
        for(;m+num.length<mat[0].length;m++){
            for(int o=0;o<num.length;o++){
                rows[o]=Arrays.copyOfRange(mat[n+o],m,m+num.length);
            }
            int p=0;
            for(;p<rows.length;p++){
                int q=0;
                for(;q < rows[0].length;q++){
                    if((rows[p][q]==1)&&(num[p][q]==1)){
                        score+=1;
                    }
                    else if((num[p][q]==1)&&(rows[p][q]==0)){
                        score-=.25;
                    }
                    else if((num[p][q]==0)&&(rows[p][q]==0)){
                        score+=.25;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(score>highest){
            highest=score;
            score=0;
        }
        else{
            score=0;
        }

    }
    return(highest);
```

My problem is that this just appears to repeat the same 13x13 block over and over again, without ever moving to a different block, either to the side or down. Any advice at all would be helpful here, I'm pulling my hair out as we speak.
EDIT:
Sample Input Number Array:

```
0000001000000
0000011000000
0000011000000
0000101000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000001000000
0000111110000
```

And I want to search through :

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

And I want to search through the second for every possible 13 x 13 matrix, compare it to the first and return a score based on their similarity, returning the highest one.

Comment: Provide a sample input and output, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Neat problem here, couldn't resist giving it a shot. This solution works with my contrived sample data, which is provided.

```
public static double compareMatrices(int[][] num, int[][] mat)
{
    double score = 0;
    double highest = 0;
    for (int numX = 0; numX <= num.length - mat.length; numX++)
    {
        for (int numY = 0; numY <= num[0].length - mat[0].length; numY++)
        {
            score = 0;
            for (int matX = 0; matX < mat.length; matX++)
            {
                for (int matY = 0; matY < mat[0].length; matY++)
                {
                    if (num[numX + matX][numY + matY] == mat[matX][matY])
                        score++;
                }
            }

            if(score >highest)
                highest = score;
        }
    }
    return highest; //highest num of elements in array that match sub-array
}
```

Sample data:

```
int[][] now = { { 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
              { 0, 0, 0, 1 }, 
              { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };

int[][] no = { { 1, 0 }, 
               { 0, 1 } };
System.out.println(compareMatrices(now, no));
```

Which outputs `4.0`, identifying the top-right sub-array as a perfect match.

Comment: I've added test cases. And I'm not so much interested in where the sub-array IS as much as what the highest score is, as I'm running it through with 9 other arrays to see which one it is most similar to. Hence the conditional statements near the end, where if they're both 1, the score increases by 1, if the current matrix's location is 0 but the input number matrix 1, it decreases by .25 and if both are 0, the score increases by .25.

Comment: @ChuckDivebomb Yes, that's what mine does. Your scoring system is unnecessarily complicated, as far as I can see, for determining similarity. If they match, add one. If not, don't. The number returned is the highest number of matches. IF you really want me to make it work with your scoring, I can do that, but it's a pretty trivial change.

Comment: I've been trying running it with different input arrays for num, but no matter what I run through it I seem to be always receiving the same score for highest, regardless of what's being fed in. Any idea what might be making it do that?

Comment: @chuckdivebomb Unless it's a fantastic coincidence, no, I don't. If you can post the exact arrays you're using (including how you input them, if you don't hard code them), I can take a look.

Comment: @ChuckDivebomb Actually, depending on the arrays you're using, I think I know exactly what might be causing your problem. However, again, I need to see them in order to make a real assessment.